# What is the right way to handle type string null values in SQL's Bulk Insert?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, error-handling, null

For example, I have a column with type int.

The raw data source has integer values, but the null values, instead of being empty (`''`), is `'NIL'`

How would I handle those values when trying to Bulk Insert into MSSQL?

My code is

```
create table test (nid INT);

bulk insert test from @FILEPATH with (format="CSV", firstrow=2);
```

the first 5 rows of my .csv file looks like

```
1
2
3
NIL
7
```

Comment: First explain exactly how you are using bulk insert. Often we insert into a staging table first and then "fix" quality issues before or while inserting into the final destination.

Comment: `INSERT` the data into a staging table, and then `INSERT` that data into your production table, and `TRY_CONVERT` your string column to an `int`.

Comment: @Larnu My column, in the pure .csv form, includes string values. those string values are "NIL". That is why I am asking, how would I bulk insert all these values into the sql database, when I have string values?

Comment: Yes, as I said, `INSERT` it into a staging table *first*, and then transform the data.

Comment: Ah sorry, I thought I read a comment that asked if my column is actually int typed. That makes sense. However, how am I supposed to transform NIL i(type string) nto '  ' (actual null value) ?

Comment: As another alternative, you could run your file through a pre-processor to convert prior to importing. That is a very common ETL technique. TSQL isn't really designed for robust ETL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the `nil` with `"` (empty string) directly in your data source file or insert the data into a staging table and transform it:

```
BULK INSERT staging_sample_data
FROM '\\data\sample_data.dat';

INSERT INTO [sample_data] 
SELECT NULLIF(ColA, 'nil'), NULLIF(ColB, 'nil'),...
```

Of course if your field is for example a numeric, the staging table should have  a string field. Then, you can do as Larnu offers: 'TRY_CONVERT(INT, ColA)'.

*Note: if there are default constraints you may need to check how to [keep nulls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/keep-nulls-or-use-default-values-during-bulk-import-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16#using-bcp-and-using-default-values-with-a-non-xml-format-file)